# mysql fetching data from server

Tags: mysql

When get new data from the database, does this mean a new connection? **mysql database**

Eg:

```
 SELECT * FROM employees WHERE ID=1
```

Does this mean a new connection on the database server?

Comment: Probably no, but depends on many factors.

Comment: *When get new data from the database, does this mean a new connection?* The phrase makes no sense. The entity which connects to the server and gets the data from the tables of databases is a client. You have told nothing about the client. Whereas the client defines does it will close the connection after the data retrieving and does it will set new connection for another query, or it will reuse existing connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do I need a connection to perform a query?**

Yes, absolutely.

**Do I need a fresh connection to get the latest data?**

No, you only need to query again.

**Does every query need a new connection?**

No, you only need one connection, then you can make several queries. Typically, you open the connection once when starting your program, and then do whatever you need; even closing the db is optional, modern languages do that for you when you exit the script, but it's nice to take care of it when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not so familiar with SQL, this is an SQL Query. It is a kind of specifying the requirements of data which you are requesting from the database. Database Connection is a different thing.

I recommend you should dig in to SQL to understand bit more, it is very easy to learn..

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean a new connection on the database server?

1. If you are already connected then no
2. If you are not connected then yes
3. If your connection hit a timeout on no activity, or similar then yes

You can see your connections (as a normal user) using:

```sql
show processlist
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-processlist.html

You can see the connection ID and if you are looking to see if your connection is changing then that will help.